# What does "slip it by me" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Fight Club (1999)*, Narrator wants Marla to choose different support group:

> Marla: I want bowel cancer.
>
> Narrator: No. No. I want bowel cancer.
>
> Marla: That's your favorite too? Tried to **slip it by me**, eh?

What does "slip it by me" mean?
I know "give somebody the slip", but this one's different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you see the comedy and morbid ridiculousness of this scene.

Imagine they are sharing sweets:  Maria: "I want the hazelnut cream./ Narrator No, I want that/ Maria: That's your favourite too?  You tried to slip (the sweet) by me? (so I didn't see you taking it)"

Maria thinks that the narrator is trying to get his favourite support group by not mentioning it and then casually taking it at the end. To "slip something by me" is to subtly take something past me.

You can also use this of a person:  "I slipped by the guards and they didn't see me". This connects to the idiom "give someone the slip".